# best practice to handle error in multilingual application

Tags: c#, multilingual

i am developing a multilingual application in which i have to consider different errors..

suggest me whether i use error code or exceptions...

Comment: What platform? What do you mean by "handle"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS SharePoint throws exceptions like this:

```
....
Throw New SPException(SPResource.GetString("CannotChangeRootwebPerm", New Object() { Me.Url }))
....
```

which sounds reasonable. - you have an utility function which knows how to find the required message for current locale; you give each exception string a readable & logical name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd always prefer Exceptions instead of arbitrary return values.
A way to create multilinguar exceptions is to create a base class which takes care of translation, i.e.:

```
class TranslatedException : Exception {
    private string translationKey = "base_exception";
    public string ToString() {
        return YourTranslationClass.GetTranslation(this.translationKey);
    }
}
```

Other exceptions just need to inherit from this class and change the translationKey accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't in be better if other exceptions still inherit from System.Exception class?

Comment: If TranslatedException inherits from the base Exception (depends on the programming language wich was not specified by the OP) then other Exceptions can safely inherit from TranslatedException without breaking any of the (bad-style) catch (Exception ex) code.

Comment: i can get the respective translation from resource file. but i just wants to know that whether I use exceptions of use error codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use exceptions. Get localized error messages from a resource file or similar. Read this:

- [Error codes or Exceptions? Why is Reliable Software so Hard?](http://damienkatz.net/2006/04/error_code_vs_e.html)